# how to observe interrupts in windows or linux ubuntu 14.04

Tags: interrupt, interrupt-handling, interruptions

everybody i want to observe interrupt handling in my system, now i'm using windows 8.1, i can use a linux ubuntu 14.04.1 on Vmware virtual machine too.
any information about interrupt handling , counting them and watching their processing is useful. is there any application that do this monitoring?
please help me, i'm in hold, 
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend trying to search for an answer before asking a question. This is shamelessly copy/pasted from http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/watch-live-interrupts.

To see the interrupts occurring on your system, run the command:

`watch -n1 "cat /proc/interrupts`"

The watch command executes another command periodically, in this case "cat /proc/interrups". The -n1 option tells watch to execute the command every second.

Try using -d for fancy output with highlights.

---

Man page link for the watch command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch

---

Introduction to Linux Interrupts (describes what /proc/interrupts is all 
about):http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/linux-interrupts/

- The first Column is the IRQ number.
- The Second column says how many times the CPU core has been interrupted.
- For interrupt like rtc [Real time clock] CPU has not being interrupted. RTC are present in electronic devices to keep track of time.
  NMI and LOC are drivers used on system that are not accessible/configured by user.
- IRQ number determines the priority of the interrupt that needs to be handled by the CPU.

A small IRQ number value means higher priority.

For example if CPU receives interrupt from Keyboard and system clock simultaneously. CPU will serve System Clock first since it has IRQ number 0.

IRQ 0 — system timer (cannot be changed);

IRQ 1 — keyboard controller (cannot be changed)

IRQ 3 — serial port controller for serial port 2 (shared with serial port 4, if present);

IRQ 4 — serial port controller for serial port 1 (shared with serial port 3, if present);

IRQ 5 — parallel port 2 and 3 or sound card;

IRQ 6 — floppy disk controller;

IRQ 7 — parallel port 1. It is used for printers or for any parallel port if a printer is not present.

---

**For Windows**

Original Question: [How can I find out what is causing interrupts on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/104131/how-can-i-find-out-what-is-causing-interrupts-on-windows)

There are a couple of answers there you may benefit from. Like [Windows Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which shows how much processor time is spent serving interrupts, [Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191077%28VS.85%29.aspx), the [xperf command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh162920.aspx), and [The DPC/ISR Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191033%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Shahriar.M. Updated for windows. There was a similar question on serverfault I got this from.